# Situation where Users can add/remove Columns

Tags: java, mysql

### Situation Overview

The current question is about a situation where the software user, the client, wants to make an evaluation of a material. This evaluation can be done with 1 or more criterias that the user can add and remove from a supervisor area of the software. Notice that the evaluation must be saved in the database for future consultation.

Extra information: The software is coded in Java.

### Objective

Suppose Three tables. Table `Material`, table `Evaluation` and Table `Criteria`.
Notice that the PK `idMaterial` is a FK in `Evaluation`.

The image below illustrates the tables:

[image]

These three tables are a simplification of the real tables. The Criteria table name the criteria variable and set its weight for the final score calculted on the evaluation.

In this case, the objective is that the user be able to add and delete criteria.
With the criteria defined, he can then create evaluations for the materials.

**And use these criterias to save an evaluation on the database.**

In other words, I need to store the score given to each user-defined criteria.

### Problem

From a technical point of view, we notice that:

1. The software would have to allow the user to delete and add columns. That is a bit tricky since if he deletes 2 columns and adds 1, the code would have to find which column he deleted and delete them only and then just add a single column. That example is tricky in the sense that, if we could just delete all columns and just add the ones he maintained/added would be easier in code.
2. Messing with table columns seems dangerous for the integrity of the table. Especially under unknown connection(?) circumstances.

I'm looking for a better and safer solution.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. I hope I made the question as clear as possible.

## Constraints

There are no constraints for a solution except that, I'm using Java and MySQL.
I can create more tables if needed and I can allow the user to add/delete columns.

Comment: From the note it looks like you can't create 3 different tables, otherwise could you not just have unused criteria be null/-1?

Comment: There are no constraints for a solution except that, Im using Java and Mysql.
I can create more tables if needed and I can allow the user to add/delete columns.

Comment: This screaming for an EAV model. While the model is hard to maintain, sometimes it is the right answer.

Comment: @Strawberry Please post this as an answer so I can mark as correct and give you points. That solved my problem. I didnt know the EAV model. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I really don't need the points. Feel free to answer your own question, and accept that, or just delete.

Comment: @Strawberry Didnt mean to upset you. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not remotely upset. I just don't feel compelled to answer further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But How Do I create an Evaluation afterwards? Since in your solution every criteria is a row... Would you exemplify, please?

We have something equal in one of our systems, where the user can define 0 upto infinite criterias for something.

Thus, you need to use rows.

In Detail, A user can attach one or more `filters` (they are `or`'d) where each filter can contain one or more `criterias` (they are `and`'d)

Evaluation from the code side looks like this. (This is no copy/paste code, but might give you an idea). `environmentVariables` is basically a map containing the objects properties on which we are trying to apply the filter:

```
public static boolean evaluate(Filter filter, Map<String, Object> environmentVariables) {
    for (Criteria criteria : filter.getCriterias()) {
        if (!evaluateCriteria(criteria, environmentVariables)) {
            // one missmatch -> false.
            return false;
        }
    }

    // all criterias matched, that filter is true.
    return true;
}

public static boolean evaluateCriteria(Criteria criteria, Map<String, Object> environmentVariables) {
    if (environmentVariables != null) {
        if (environmentVariables.containsKey(criteria.getKey())) {
            return evaluateCriteria(criteria, environmentVariables.get(criteria.getKey()));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean evaluateCriteria(Criteria criteria, Object value) {
    switch (criteria.getOperator()) {
        case LIKE:
            if (value != null) {
                return value.toString().toLowerCase().contains(criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase());
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        //other OperatorTypes
        case STARTSWITH: // code...
        case ENDSWITH: // code...
        case EQUALS: // code...
        case GREATER_THAN: // code...
        case GREATER_THAN_EQUAL: // code...
        case LESSER_THAN: // code...
        case LESSER_THAN_EQUAL: // code...
        default:
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException(criteria.getOperator() + " is not defined");

    }
}
```

Comment: I see. In my case, the user will use ALL criterias. How do I store the evaluation on the database? I mean. Do I use BLOB or...

Comment: @KenobiShan I don't understand what you mean by `store the evaluation`? Criterias are stored in the database - evaluation is performed during runtime.

Comment: In my case, I must save the evaluations.

Comment: 1 Evaluation has 1..n criterias that must be saved.

Comment: I made clarifications on the question. Im sorry, I should have explicited that I must save the evaluations with the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment then, you should just create a table for criteria, where the user adds a row which specifies what the evaluation criterion is. This will be much safer to add and delete to as you are not altering the actual table properties, but instead manipulating entries

**EDIT**:

To use this simply use an `INSERT INTO` statement, where you insert the values into the columns.

Comment: But How Do I create an Evaluation afterwards? Since in your solution every criteria is a row... Would you exemplify, please?

Comment: See edits, not entirely sure how your application will work so I can't give you specifics but there is a generic explanation

Comment: @KenobiShan Depends on: How do you evaluate criterias? In a Query, or through some programming language? As your Problem (1) describes: If there are different counts of criterias possible, columns are a bad idea. You need to use rows in order to achieve a `0...n` relationship between Material and criteria.

Comment: The problem is: in my conception every criteria would be a column of a table of evaluations. I dont understand how Am I supposed to connect a criteria from a row to a column...

Comment: I made clarifications on the question. Im sorry, I should have explicited that I must save the evaluations with the criteria.

Answer (score -2):

add the extra table criteria with two foreign features as primary key..two solutions exist the last one as i said and this you have draw